# how to plot a graph from .csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data in the *.csv* file as  below:

[image]

How can I plot the graph for that data in pandas

Comment: I found the first question tagged [pandas] and [plot] and closed your question because of how whimsically broad it is. Good luck!

Comment: Here are some helpful links for future reference: [ask]; providing a [mcve].